# Infinite subprocess waiting method

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

What is the difference between,

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("An infinite subprocess with constant output.")
process.wait()
```

and

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("An infinite subprocess with constant output.")
```

When the second program is run, it also waits for the subprocess to exit (CTRL-C). So what is the difference between these programs ? I read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) that `process.wait()` uses busy-waiting which I guess increases CPU overhead. Does the second program avoid busy waiting ?

Comment: Yes, the second snippet avoids busy-waiting.

Comment: @Selcuk The code exits before 5 seconds in REPL if that's your point. In my example the second code runs a video transcoder (ffmpeg), and it continues running until I give an exit command. I don't know what is different between these.

Comment: @martineau But does it wait for the subprocess to finish if it is not an infinite one ? I mean does the subprocess has the time to finish it's job if the Python interpreter reaches end of the code ?

Comment: Max: No, it launches the other process and continues on it's merry way. Using `wait()` prevents that until it terminates and the return code can be obtained or it times-out.

Comment: @martineau If the code ends early, does the process become an independent process and continue running ? Because that seems like what is happening when I run the code.

Comment: Max: I think it's always an independent process — the call to `wait()` just determines whether the parent process "watches" what it does or not.

Comment: @martineau I just tried that (without the wait), the subprocess was creating output to the console, than I entered CTRL-C, and `KeyboardInterrupt` occurred rather than the process' internal excepting handling system. Which makes it seem like Python was still running even though the code only consists of the `Popen` call.

Comment: @martineau Sorry it seems the `wait()` call was still in the code when I ran that test, so please ignore my last comment.